# Linearlayout overlay another linearlayout

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, overlay, android-linearlayout

I have some problem with add linearlayout dynamically. It's add on the top of screen, overlay other linearlayout.

Here XML,code and results.

XML:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/top_km"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="#888"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="30dip"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/top_km"
        android:id="@id/textLayout">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Code:

```
myLayout = (RelativeLayout) page.findViewById(R.id.textLayout);
LinearLayout linLayout = new LinearLayout(this);  
linLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
myLayout.addView(linLayout);
LinearLayout hozLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
hozLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
myLayout.addView(hozLayout);
```

Results:
[enter link description here](http://i40.tinypic.com/vmu49i.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a `RelativeLayout` as your holder. Use a `LinearLayout` with `orientation="vertical"` instead.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/top_km"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@id/textLayout" />
```

then in code

`myLayout = (LinearLayout) page.findViewById(R.id.textLayout);`

followed by

```
// rest of your code
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you use **RealativeLayout** for proper adding use
 1. RelativeLayout.LayoutParams for st LayoutParams
 2. In LayoutParams use field **below**

Example:

```
RelativeLayout rl=new RelativeLayout(this);
LinearLayout ll1=new LinearLayout(this);
TextView tx1=new TextView(this);
tx1.setText("Test1");
ll1.addView(tx1);
rl.addView(ll1);
LinearLayout ll2=new LinearLayout(this);
TextView tx2=new TextView(this);
tx2.setText("Test1");
ll2.addView(tx1);
rl.addView(ll2);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp2=(LayoutParams) ll2.getLayoutParams();
```

And then use **lp2.addRule**

Here some help:

Parameters
verb    One of the verbs defined by RelativeLayout, such as ALIGN_WITH_PARENT_LEFT.
anchor  The id of another view to use as an anchor, or a boolean value(represented as TRUE) for true or 0 for false). For verbs that don't refer to another sibling (for example, ALIGN_WITH_PARENT_BOTTOM) just use -1.

Comment: I have tried to do this:

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM,id_value_layout-1);
    hozLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
But the situation is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's easier for you to add it in the XML file with `android:visibility="GONE"` and then in the code just show it (`View.VISIBLE`) or hide it (`View.GONE`).

Comment: No (( I do not know the number of LinearLayout. May be 10 or may be 100.

Comment: So, why don't use a ListView then, with your layouts as the rows, easier to code. Anyway, if you still want to do it programmatically (which is discouraged, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827819/best-practices-layouts-on-android-programmatic-vs-xml) then do it as Ken Wolf says, with a LinearLayout as a container