# Programmatically generate a table layout inside a programmatically generated grid view in Android

Tags: android, gridview, android-tablelayout

[image: Dynamically generating table layout inside dynamically generated grid view] 
  I have to dynamically generate a table layout inside a dynamically generated grid view in Android. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. You can create layouts programattically  also but it is recommenced to use XML layouts instead of doing it programattically. Read this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827819/best-practices-layouts-on-android-programmatic-vs-xml) for more information.

Comment: Actually i have to implement this layout in a Tab Widget. Can you be more specific how to do that by showing me any example.