# Android proper way to fit layout on all devices horizontally and vertically

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

Hello I want to ask about the most *efficient* way to adjust layout in all devices mobile and tablets sometimes I can't  use `wrap_content` and `layout_weight` 
 I set size in some percentage to the device size in java like this:

```
   ImageView img;
   Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
   width = display.getWidth();
   height = display.getHeight();
   img.getLayoutParams().width = width* 7 / 10;
```

and when rotating screen I use this method to change percentage

```
if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE&& getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet)) {
width=(int) (width * 0.7);
}
```

I am asking If this procedure is more efficient than using multi XML files for each screen size / orientation

Comment: Android tools convert XML layouts into code, so there's no inherent problem with using XML layouts versus dynamic

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best practices: Layouts on Android (Programmatic vs XML)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827819/best-practices-layouts-on-android-programmatic-vs-xml)

Comment: @Charuka it's not the same as my question I  am not saying I am using java to construct views  instead of XML nope I am using XML and my issues was controlling width & height even dynamically or in XML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it depends on the scenario. Sometimes maintaining xml is efficient and easy sometimes dynamic calculation is necessary.  You can go through the link     https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html . It will give you some ideas. In your above code for width/height calculation sometimes you may not get proper result for some devices. Below is the code that will support all version of android device Resolution(Width, Height) accurately at runtime.

```
private void calculateDeviceResolution(Activity context) {
    Display display = context.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
        //new pleasant way to get real metrics
        DisplayMetrics realMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        display.getRealMetrics(realMetrics);
        realWidth = realMetrics.widthPixels;
        realHeight = realMetrics.heightPixels;

    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
        //reflection for this weird in-between time
        try {
            Method mGetRawH = Display.class.getMethod("getRawHeight");
            Method mGetRawW = Display.class.getMethod("getRawWidth");
            realWidth = (Integer) mGetRawW.invoke(display);
            realHeight = (Integer) mGetRawH.invoke(display);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //this may not be 100% accurate, but it's all we've got
            realWidth = display.getWidth();
            realHeight = display.getHeight();
            Constants.errorLog("Display Info", "Couldn't use reflection to get the real display metrics.");
        }

    } else {
        //This should be close, as lower API devices should not have window navigation bars
        realWidth = display.getWidth();
        realHeight = display.getHeight();
    }
}
```

Comment: Its my pleasure..:)